# VimL print values in a list infinitly

Tags: vim

I have a list of symbols, and want to use the Vim8 timers API to loop over the symbols list every 80ms and return that symbol. I worked out something like this:

```
let s:frames = ['⠋', '⠙', '⠹', '⠸', '⠼', '⠴', '⠦', '⠧', '⠇', '⠏']
let s:numTestimonials = len(s:frames)
let s:start = 0

function! PrintValues()
    return s:frames[s:start]
    let s:start = (s:start) + 1 % s:numTestimonials
endfunction

let timer = timer_start(80, 'PrintValues', {'repeat': -1})
```

But as soon as it reaches the last symbol in the list, it will throw an error, `E684: list index out of range: 10`. Any ideas how to accomplish what I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have the 1 inside parentheses before the mod

```
let s:start = (s:start + 1) % s:numTestimonials
```

`1 % s:numTestimonials` is always 1 and is evaluated before adding s:start

Comment: d'oh... I did have that originally but it was giving me issues regarding some other syntax error though. Thanks for the answer! Now to figure out how to print the returned value in a statusline segment

Answer (score 2):

Some little changes made to your code (Tested on vim 7.4):

```
let timer = timer_start(500, 'PrintValues', {'repeat': -1})
let s:frames = ['⠋', '⠙', '⠹', '⠸', '⠼', '⠴', '⠦', '⠧', '⠇', '⠏']
let s:numTestimonials = len(s:frames)
let s:start = 0

function! PrintValues(timer)
    execute "normal! i".s:frames[s:start]
    let s:start = (s:start + 1) % s:numTestimonials
endfunction
```

[image]